# mysqli connection done in __construct and cause too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have mysqli connection that is created in the __construct part of my database class:

```
    public function __construct() {
    $link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);
}
```

because of that, every time that I want to create an object of a database (for query) It's create new connection, and that cause "Too many connections" in my script.

The way I am calling to the database (from another class) is like this:

```
$db = new Database;
$db->query("SELECT language_iso_code FROM languages WHERE language_iso_code = ");
```

Is there another way to call the query function? Or maybe a way to pass the connection of mysqli to another classes?

Comment: Exactly how many times do you use `new Database` per script? And yes, you can pass the object into methods and other functions as an argument, so its visible inside the scope of that method or function.

Comment: what i did is a class of the DB and every time i want to use the database for a query i need to create new object. the website include a lot of files and classes. I must use the "new Database" to let it have it no?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to use a static variable for your class and only connect to the database if the connections not up:

```
class Example {
    private static link = null;

    public function __construct() {
        if(self::$link === null) {
            self::link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this answer: **it will not solve the problem**

Comment: my question is - is this how it's done in all the big programs? cms? or there is another way? for example in wordpress, drupal or whatever framework there is... how do they use a query in different file, different class without create new object? or they do and use the static option that you suggested?

Comment: @YourCommonSense you have any idea what will solve the problem maybe?